Ollama Function cannot import '_set_config_context' from 'langchain_core.runnables.config'
as a follow-up to the thread on using Ollama for with_structured_output() instead of using OpenAI or Mistral, the ollama_functions.py needs to import from langchain_core.tools that imports from langchain_core.runnables.config for _set_config_context.
But I get an ImportError "cannot import name '_set_config_context' from 'langchain_core.runnables.config'. This is expected given the leading underscore indicating the internal-use of the function.
Is there some workaround here for the import?
Import overview:
File ~/dry_run/ollama_functions.py:35
     33 from langchain_core.runnables.base import RunnableMap
     34 from langchain_core.runnables.passthrough import RunnablePassthrough
---> 35 from langchain_core.tools import BaseTool
     37 DEFAULT_SYSTEM_TEMPLATE = """You have access to the following tools:
     38 
     39 {tools}
   (...)
     46 }}
     47 """  # noqa: E501
     49 DEFAULT_RESPONSE_FUNCTION = {
     50     "name": "__conversational_response",
     51     "description": (
   (...)
     63     },
     64 }

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/tools.py:67
     60 from langchain_core.retrievers import BaseRetriever
     61 from langchain_core.runnables import (
     62     Runnable,
     63     RunnableConfig,
     64     RunnableSerializable,
     65     ensure_config,
     66 )
---> 67 from langchain_core.runnables.config import (
     68     _set_config_context,
     69     patch_config,
     70     run_in_executor,
     71 )
     72 from langchain_core.runnables.utils import accepts_context
     75 class SchemaAnnotationError(TypeError):

I tested importing patch_config from the same .config file without any problem.
The _set_config_context function looks like this:
def _set_config_context(config: RunnableConfig) -> None:
    """Set the child runnable config + tracing context

    Args:
        config (RunnableConfig): The config to set.
    """
    from langsmith import (
        RunTree,  # type: ignore
        run_helpers,  # type: ignore
    )

    var_child_runnable_config.set(config)
    if hasattr(RunTree, "from_runnable_config"):
        # import _set_tracing_context, get_tracing_context
        rt = RunTree.from_runnable_config(dict(config))
        tc = run_helpers.get_tracing_context()
        run_helpers._set_tracing_context({**tc, "parent": rt})





My work-around goes like this:

add ContextVar to your tools.py imports:
from contextvars import copy_context, ContextVar

copy this modified code from config.py into tools.py. Note that I have placed the instantiation of var_child_runnable_config inside the function _set_config_context and the import from langsmith outside the function:


from langsmith import (RunTree, run_helpers,)
def _set_config_context(config: RunnableConfig) -> None:
var_child_runnable_config = ContextVar(
"child_runnable_config", default=RunnableConfig())

var_child_runnable_config.set(config)

if hasattr(RunTree, "from_runnable_config"):
    # import _set_tracing_context, get_tracing_context
    rt = RunTree.from_runnable_config(dict(config))
    tc = run_helpers.get_tracing_context()
    run_helpers._set_tracing_context({**tc, "parent": rt})


comment out or delete the line as shown below, also in tools.py:
from langchain_core.runnables.config import (
     patch_config,
     run_in_executor,
     #_set_config_context,
 )



I do not know the reason tools.py will not import _set_config_context, I got the same results as you while investigating, the other two imported functions did not give me an error either.
As you know, the leading underscore in a Python function name is a convention to indicate that a function is intended for use internal to its own module only, and should not be imported/exported. But it still can be. I do not know if third-party modules such as Pydantic can enforce this. When I tested the code after removing all underscores, the same error persisted.
This issue seems to have cropped-up in the last two weeks or so, the code worked fine for me when I ran it at that time.

Try to update the related packages.
In my case, when I do:
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_openai_tools_agent

I also get the error:
ImportError: cannot import name '_set_config_context' from 'langchain_core.runnables.config'

Then I update the langchain and langchain-core to latest version, the problem was fixed.
see issue
